# Python to create buy month from date

Tags: python

I need to create a column in the data frame for a buy month that is from the 22nd of the month through the 21st of the next month.
The buymonth should be just be the first day of the month .
Example:
date        buymonth
12/17/16 >> 12/01/16
12/23/16 >> 01/01/17

I have tried lots of code but always get an error when trying to compare the day greater than 21

```
If df.loc[:,'date'].dt.day > 21:
```

Throws the error 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
tmp2["buymonth"] = tmp2['date'] + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

Gives me the error
TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` and pandas' date offset functionality.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin

df = DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=365)})
df.loc[:, 'buymonth'] = np.where(df.loc[:,'date'].dt.day > 21, 
        df.loc[:,'date'] + MonthBegin(1), 
        df.loc[:,'date'] + MonthBegin(1) - MonthBegin(1))

df.iloc[20:30]
Out[9]: 
         date   buymonth
20 2010-01-21 2010-01-01
21 2010-01-22 2010-02-01
22 2010-01-23 2010-02-01
23 2010-01-24 2010-02-01
24 2010-01-25 2010-02-01
25 2010-01-26 2010-02-01
26 2010-01-27 2010-02-01
27 2010-01-28 2010-02-01
28 2010-01-29 2010-02-01
29 2010-01-30 2010-02-01
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did have to use pd.DatetimeIndex where 'date' was being added to the  pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)                                           df.loc[:, 'buymonth'] = np.where(df.loc[:,'date'].dt.day > 21, 
        pd.DatetimeIndex(df.loc[:,'date']) + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), 
        pd.DatetimeIndex(df.loc[:,'date']) + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))